# MPI_Testsome and MPI_Iprobe in C

Tags: c, mpi

I have a piece of MPI C code which looks something like the following:

```
for(i=0;i<NTask;i++)
{
  got_initial_bit_of_data[i]=0;
  if(need_to_communicate with i)
     MPI_ISend(&bit_of_pre_data_for_i,1,MPI_INT,partner,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&pre_requests[i]);
}
while(1)
{
  MPI_Testsome(NTask,pre_requests,&ndone,idxs,MPI_STATUSES_IGNORE)
  if(ndone)
  {
    for(i=0;i<ndone;i++)
    {
      MPI_ISend(&the_main_block_of_data_for_i,size_of_block,MPI_BYTE,idxs[i],1,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&main_requests[idxs[i]]);
    }
  }
  //Other stuff that doesn't matter
  MPI_IProbe(MPI_ANY_SOURCE,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&flag,&status);
  if(!flag)
  {
    MPI_IProbe(MPI_ANY_SOURCE,1,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&flag,&status);
  }
  if(flag)
  {
    //Receiving the initial little bit of data
    if(status.MPI_TAG==0)
    {
      //Location 1
      got_initial_bit_of_data[status.MPI_SOURCE]=1;
      MPI_Recv(&useful_location,1,MPI_INT,status.MPI_SOURCE,MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
    }
    //Receiving the main bit of data
    else if(status.MPI_TAG==1)
    {
      //Location 2
      if(got_initial_bit_of_data[status.MPI_SOURCE]!=1)
        //Something has gone horribly wrong...
      //Receive the main bit of data here...
    }
  }
}
```

Obviously I've omitted lots of details because the full code is several hundreds of lines long.  If something I've done looks a bit odd, it's probably because it is because of something in the omitted code block.

The idea is that at the start each processor sends an "announcement" message to those processors it wants to talk to.  When it detects that those processors have received this message (that is when MPI_Testsome indicates the "announcement" MPI_Isend is complete), it should send a big chunk of data.

From the point of view of a processor receiving data, it should first receive the announcement message at location 1, which will cause MPI_Testsome to indicate that the Isend is complete and send the big chunk of data.  The receiving processor should then receive the main block of data at location 2.  Following this logic, it should be impossible to reach location 2 with got_initial_bit_of_data[status.MPI_SOURCE] being 0, but this is precisely what does happen very occasionally and I'd like to work out why.

Either I've got the logic of the code wrong, or there's some subtlety of IProbe and Testsome that I'm missing.

I'm also exiting and re-entering this entire block of code, with different processors moving in and out at different points in time, but only when all their ISends have been processed (as determined by Testsome saying that they're completed).

If the above explanation doesn't make any sense, what I want to know is are there any circumstances under which Testsome claim that an ISend is completed *without* the matching receive completing (or even starting)?  Is a processor making a call to IProbe enough to cause Testsome to consider a request completed for instance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If the above explanation doesn't make any sense, what I want to know is are there any circumstances under which Testsome claim that an ISend is completed without the matching receive completing (or even starting)? Is a processor making a call to IProbe enough to cause Testsome to consider a request completed for instance?

All that MPI_Testsome guarantees is that the buffer you were using from ISend is no longer needed by MPI.  If you want to guarantee that the recipient has started the receive, use the synchronous form, ISSend.

Comment: Amazing.  An extra s and my problem is gone!  So I understand why this works, if I just use Isend, testsome will return "complete" as soon as the data is gone from the local process (for instance if it's copied to some network buffer), even if the receiving processor hasn't started to receive it yet?

Comment: You should have a read through the [MPI-2](http://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi22-report/mpi22-report.htm) documentation if you are going to be doing any serious development in MPI :)

Comment: I read the documentation for Isend/Testsome and Iprobe (the first few google results for them anyway), which are full of brief statements like "Begins a nonblocking send".  The size of the full MPI documentation is pretty daunting.  I'll put the full MPI documentation on my to-read list, thank you for clearing up this particular problem.

Comment: @user1356855, completion of the _standard send_ operations (`MPI_SEND` and `MPI_ISEND`) means that the data buffer is not going to be accessed again by MPI: _"... the message data and envelope have been safely stored away so that the sender is free to modify the send buffer. The message might be copied directly into the matching receive buffer, or it might be copied into a temporary system buffer."_ (§3.4 Communication Modes, MPI-2.2)